# Insert rows based on the user input (textbox value)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert rows in a table using user input (textbox) alongwith formula and incremental row serial numbers

I have tried below mentioned code

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").visible = true
Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").select
Sheet1.activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(9+1).Entirerow.insertshift := xldown
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(9).resize(Cint(textbox1.value)).filldown
```

every time i click button it inserts single row instead of user input

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLNr.png)

Comment: **1.** Why are you unhiding "Sheet1" if you are trying to insert the rows in "Sheets" **2** Where are you using the "textbox1" value to insert the rows? I see you are telling it to insert just a single row which excel is doing it. **3** Please put your query in the post and not the title of the post. Give it an appropriate heading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please note that I have hide that sheet as there are multiple sheets for singe, double or triple vendor comparison so user will select only that sheet which he required, as per the value in textbox1, that number of rows will be inserted below serial no. 1 (ref. screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

While I do not understand clearly what you want to do, I think the bellow code will help.

Please adjust it to your needs.

```
Sub add_some_fancy_rows()
Dim Resizer As Integer
Dim a As Variant
a = InputBox("Please enter the number of rows you want to autofill", "Let me do it for you") 'First we ask for user input

On Error GoTo notvalid  'We add an error handler, so if the user would enter text like "seven", the sub will exit with a message
Resizer = CInt(a)       'we store the input in a variable which has to be an integer, if the user enters text it will couse an error so we jump to the end
If Resizer < 2 Then GoTo notvalid 'We also check if the number is higher than 1, othervise it couses error, or copies the 8th row to the 9th
On Error GoTo 0 'We reset the error handling so we can see if something else goes wrong.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(9 + 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown 'add a new row under the 9th row/above the 10th row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(9).Resize(Resizer).FillDown
  Exit Sub    'We exit the sub before the error message.
notvalid: 'in case of error we jump here
    MsgBox "Please enter a number which is 2 or higher"
End Sub
```

I hope it helps

Comment: it is inserting row above sl. no. 1 line, also no formula is copied

Comment: For me it does copy the formulas as well, could you please specify?

Comment: not working, it is inserting row anywhere inspite im entering value like 5, 10 or 11, also formula are not copying